# Using Factory Boy with GeoDjango PointFields

Tags: python, django, gis, geodjango, factory-boy

I'm working on writing tests for a new GeoDjango project I've started. Normally I used [Factory Boy](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) and [Faker](https://github.com/joke2k/faker) to create model instances for testing. However it's not clear to me how you can mock GeoDjango PointField fields. When looking at the record in [Spacialite](http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/) it appears as a binary blob.

I'm totally new to GIS stuff, and a little confused as to how I can create factories for PointFields in Django.

```python
# models.py

from django.contrib.gis.db import models

class Place(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    location = models.PointField(blank=True, null=True)

    objects = models.GeoManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % self.name
```

```python
# factories.py

import factory
from faker import Factory as FakerFactory
from . import models

faker = FakerFactory.create()

class PlaceFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Place

    name = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda x: faker.name())
    #location = What do I do?
```

Comment: If you are not fixed on Factory Boy, checkout this extension for model-mommy (by now my preferred library for creating test records): https://github.com/sigma-geosistemas/mommy_spatial_generators

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe you need to create a custom fuzzy attribute for point instances. Can you try this? Right now I don't have the setup to run it all through.

```
import random
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point
from factory.fuzzy import BaseFuzzyAttribute

class FuzzyPoint(BaseFuzzyAttribute):
    def fuzz(self):
        return Point(random.uniform(-180.0, 180.0),
                     random.uniform(-90.0, 90.0))


class PlaceFactory(FakerFactory):
    name = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda x: faker.name())
    location = FuzzyPoint()
    class Meta:
        model = models.Place
```

Answer (score 11):

Fussy is about to be [deprecated](https://github.com/FactoryBoy/factory_boy/issues/271/) as [Factory Boy documentation](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fuzzy.html#module-factory.fuzzy) says.

> Now that FactoryBoy includes the factory.Faker class, most of these built-in fuzzers are deprecated in favor of their Faker equivalents.

As [@Steven B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/935351/steven-b) said, you must create your own provider. I did some changes to his code in order to make the provider as generic as possible.

```
class DjangoGeoPointProvider(BaseProvider):

    def geo_point(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['coords_only'] = True
        # # generate() is not working in later Faker versions
        # faker = factory.Faker('local_latlng', **kwargs)
        # coords = faker.generate()  
        faker = factory.faker.faker.Faker()
        coords = faker.local_latlng(**kwargs)
        return Point(x=float(coords[1]), y=float(coords[0]), srid=4326)
```

***Note**: `coords_only` must be always true because we just need `lat` and `long` values, without any extra metadata.*

***Note 2**: `generate()` is deprecated, see [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54306235/2996101).*

Finally, it is like using the `local_latlng` [provider](https://faker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/locales/pt_PT.html#faker.providers.geo.pt_PT.Provider.local_latlng) or any of the built-in providers. Here is a full example:

```py
class TargetFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    factory.Faker.add_provider(DjangoGeoPointProvider)

    class Meta:
        model = Target

    radius = factory.Faker('random_int', min=4500, max=90000)
    location = factory.Faker('geo_point', country_code='US')
```

***Note**: 'US' is the default country code, it could be omitted in this example, but you could use any of the other specified countries code in Faker doc.*

Answer (score 2):

[Faker](https://faker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/providers/faker.providers.geo.html) already has some nice geo features. You can create you own provider to make it work for Django, for example:

```py
import factory
from faker.providers import BaseProvider
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point

class DjangoGeoLocationProvider(BaseProvider):

    countries = ['NL', 'DE', 'FR', 'BE']

    # uses faker.providers.geo
    def geolocation(self, country=None):
        country_code = country or factory.Faker('random_element', elements=self.countries).generate()
        faker = factory.Faker('local_latlng', country_code=country_code, coords_only=True)
        coords = faker.generate()
        return Point(x=float(coords[1]), y=float(coords[0]), srid=4326)
```

Which will generate Django compatible Points for the given countries.

After registering it:

```py
factory.Faker.add_provider(DjangoGeoLocationProvider)
```

You can use it in your DjangoModelFactory like any of the built-in providers:

```py
from factory.django import DjangoModelFactory as Factory

class PlaceFactory(Factory):

    class Meta:
        model = Place

    location = factory.Faker('geolocation')
    # or
    another_location = factory.Faker('geolocation', country='NL')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also set the value directly.

```
import json

from factory import LazyAttribute
from factory.django import DjangoModelFactory


class PlaceFactory(DjangoModelFactory):
    static_location = "{'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [1,1]}"
    random_location = LazyAttribute(lambda x: json.dumps({
        'type': 'Point',
        'coordinates': [random.uniform(-180.0, 180.0), random.uniform(-180.0, 180.0)]}
    ))
```