# Change default faker locale in factory_boy

Tags: python, django, factory-boy

How can I set the default locale in Python's factory_boy for all of my Factories?

In docs says that one should set it with `factory.Faker.override_default_locale` but that does nothing to my fakers...

```
import factory
from app.models import Example
from custom_fakers import CustomFakers

# I use custom fakers, this indeed are added
factory.Faker.add_provider(CustomFakers)
# But not default locales
factory.Faker.override_default_locale('es_ES')

class ExampleFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = Example

    name = factory.Faker('first_name')


>>> from example import ExampleFactory
>>> e1 = ExampleFactory()
>>> e1.name
>>> u'Chad'
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**UPD** As I said, this solution is suboptimal:

- `factory.Faker._DEFAULT_LOCALE` is a private field
- `fake()` and `faker()` use the private interface
- `fake()` doesn't work since [`factory-boy==3.1.0`](https://github.com/FactoryBoy/factory_boy/commit/f0a4ef008f07f8d42221565d8c33b88083f0be6d#diff-f57bbc6d43cc8512bb7a1ec249ce840ef810026b67792af1b4d2840c0b914bd8R46)
- if I were to use `faker`, I'd use it directly, not via `factory-boy`

You should generally prefer the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45894829/52499). Leaving this one for posterity.

---

Not a good solution, but for now it's as good as it gets. You can change the [variable](https://github.com/FactoryBoy/factory_boy/blob/v2.9.0/factory/faker.py#L58) that holds the value:

```
import factory
factory.Faker._DEFAULT_LOCALE = 'xx_XX'
```

Moreover, you can create a file like this (`app/faker.py`):

```
import factory
from faker.providers import BaseProvider

factory.Faker._DEFAULT_LOCALE = 'xx_XX'

def fake(name):
    return factory.Faker(name).generate({})

def faker():
    return factory.Faker._get_faker()

class MyProvider(BaseProvider):
    def category_name(self):
        return self.random_element(category_names)
    ...
factory.Faker.add_provider(MyProvider)

category_names = [...]
```

Then, once you import the file, the locale changes. Also, you get your providers and an easy way to use `factory_boy`'s faker outside of the factories:

```
from app.faker import fake
print(fake('random_int'))
print(faker().random_int())
```

Comment: Faker 5.6.5 (and possibly all versions > 4.17.1) doesn't have `generate()` but have `evaluate(None, None, {"locale": None})`.

Comment: @frost-nzcr4 `generate()` belonged to [`factory-boy`](https://github.com/FactoryBoy/factory_boy/blob/3.0.1/factory/faker.py#L44), not `faker`, but since `factory-boy==3.1.0` the [interface changed](https://github.com/FactoryBoy/factory_boy/commit/f0a4ef008f07f8d42221565d8c33b88083f0be6d#diff-f57bbc6d43cc8512bb7a1ec249ce840ef810026b67792af1b4d2840c0b914bd8R46). See my updated answer.

Answer (score 13):

The `Faker.override_default_locale()` is a context manager, although it's not very clear from the docs.

As such, to change the default locale for a part of a test:

```
with factory.Faker.override_default_locale('es_ES'):
    ExampleFactory()
```

For the whole test:

```
@factory.Faker.override_default_locale('es_ES')
def test_foo(self):
    user = ExampleFactory()
```

For all the tests (Django):

```
# settings.py
TEST_RUNNER = 'myproject.testing.MyTestRunner'

# myproject/testing.py
import factory
from django.conf import settings
from django.util import translation
import django.test.runner

class MyTestRunner(django.test.runner.DiscoverRunner):
    def run_tests(self, test_labels, extra_tests=None, **kwargs):
        with factory.Faker.override_default_locale(translation.to_locale(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)):
            return super().run_tests(test_labels, extra_tests=extra_tests, **kwargs)
```

More on it [here](https://github.com/FactoryBoy/factory_boy/issues/407#issuecomment-754281399).

Answer (score 3):

I'm having same issue as yours. For a temporary solution try passing locale in factory.Faker.

For example:

```
name = factory.Faker('first_name', locale='es_ES')
```

Comment: yup, I know, but is not what I wanted to do :( devs of the project aren't too responsive this days neither :(

Answer (score 3):

With Django, you can simply insert the following lines in `<myproject>/settings.py`:

```py
import factory
factory.Faker._DEFAULT_LOCALE = 'fr_FR'
```

Comment: It's best to change the locale in the [runner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45894829/52499).

Comment: Indeed, now that you altered the answer, I realize that you can apply the context manager to all tests. However, I still think my solution is simpler, and as we all know, "Simple is better than complex."

Comment: You're apparently using the private part of the interface, one day it may break. Like it did in [another case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55549083/52499). I had to update the answer, since it stopped working with recent `factory-boy`.

Answer (score 0):

Further to @xelnor's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45894829/432849), if using `pytest` (instead of Django `manage.py test`), add a [`hookwrapper`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/how-to/writing_hook_functions.html#hookwrapper-executing-around-other-hooks) on the `pytest_runtestloop` hook in your `conftest.py` to set the default locale for all the tests:

```py
@pytest.hookimpl(hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_runtestloop(session):
    with factory.Faker.override_default_locale(translation.to_locale(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)):
        outcome = yield
```